# How to encode data for sending throught socket in php?

Tags: php, sockets

The problem is that when i'm trying to send some number or string with number or some symbols trough the socket it sends with some extra symbols. For example when i trying to send `<ping>14399</ping>` on the other side from CURL result i get `string(18) "14399"`. For sending i use `socket_write($client->getSocket(), $text, strlen($text))`. How to encode the data ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably not in the sending through the socket, since `<ping>14399</ping>` is exactly 18 characters long. Possibly the output is displayed by a browser and the markups in `<` `>` are thereby dropped.